# Doctrine DQL Query works on localhost, but not on staging

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm

I am using DQL to select a dataset joining a few tables together.

My working DQL query below (apologize for the outrageous size of the code).

```
$qb            = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
    $articles_only = ( Content::TYPE_ARTICLE == $type );

    if( $countonly ){

        $qb->select('COUNT(DISTINCT d.id)')
           ->from('Entities\Content', 'd')
           ->join('d.subcategory', 's')
           ->leftjoin('d.subcategory_contents', 'c');
    }
    else{

        if( $articles_only ){
            //ignore brand(s)
            $qb->select('partial d.{id, title, type, rank, about_title, super_short_title, short_title, expiry, slug, status, tile_title, tile_description, category_sticky, exclusive, homepage_sticky, show_on_category, updated, created}, partial s.{id, title, slug, homepage_tag}, r, i');
        }
        else{
            $qb->select('partial d.{id, title, type, rank, about_title, super_short_title, short_title, expiry, slug, status, tile_title, tile_description, category_sticky, exclusive, homepage_sticky, show_on_category, updated, created}, partial s.{id, title, slug, homepage_tag}, b, r, i');
        }

        $qb->distinct()

           ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN d.expiry < :today THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS HIDDEN expired')

           ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN r.homepage_rank IS NULL THEN '.$toprank.' ELSE r.homepage_rank END) AS HIDDEN homepage_rank')
           ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN r.category_rank IS NULL THEN '.$toprank.' ELSE r.category_rank END) AS HIDDEN category_rank')
           ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN r.subcategory_rank IS NULL THEN '.$toprank.' ELSE r.subcategory_rank END) AS HIDDEN subcategory_rank')
           ->addSelect('(CASE WHEN r.default_rank IS NULL THEN '.$toprank.' ELSE r.default_rank END) AS HIDDEN default_rank')

           ->from('Entities\Content', 'd')
           ->join('d.subcategory', 's')
           ->leftjoin('d.subcategory_contents', 'c')
           ->leftjoin('d.content_rank', 'r')
           ->leftjoin('d.tile_image', 'i');

        if( ! $articles_only ){
            $qb->leftjoin('d.brand', 'b');
        }

        $qb->setParameter('today', new \DateTime());

    }

    //get online content only
    $qb->andWhere('d.status = :status')->setParameter('status', Content::STATUS_ONLINE);

    if( $type ){

        if( is_array( $type ) ) {
            $qb->andWhere('d.type IN (:type)')->setParameter('type', $type);
        }
        else
            $qb->andWhere('d.type = :type')->setParameter('type', $type);

    }

    if( $subcategory ) {

        //--- subcategory content ---//

        if( is_array($subcategory) ){

            $subs_ids = array();

            foreach($subcategory as $s)
                $subs_ids[] = $s->getId();

            $qb->andWhere('s.id IN (:subcategory)')->setParameter('subcategory', $subs_ids);

            if( ! $countonly )
                $qb->addOrderBy('category_rank', 'ASC');

        }else{

            $qb->andWhere('s.id = :subcategory OR c.subcategory = :subcategory')->setParameter('subcategory', $subcategory->getId());

            if( ! $countonly )
                $qb->addOrderBy('subcategory_rank', 'ASC');
        }

       if( ! $countonly ){
           $qb->addOrderBy('expired', 'ASC');
           $qb->addOrderBy('d.category_sticky', 'DESC');
       }

        //--- subcategory content ---//

    } else {

        //--- homepage content ---//

        if( ! $articles_only ){
            $qb->andWhere('d.expiry IS NULL OR d.expiry >= :today')->setParameter('today', $today);
        }

        if( ! $countonly ) {
            $qb->addOrderBy('homepage_rank', 'ASC');
            $qb->addOrderBy('d.homepage_sticky', 'DESC'); // no subcategory so order by home page sticky
        }
        //--- homepage content ---//

    }

    if( ! $countonly ){

        $qb->addOrderBy('d.updated', 'DESC');

        $qb->setFirstResult($offset);
        $qb->setMaxResults($limit);

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

        if( $enable_cache ){
            $query->setResultCacheLifetime(30);
            $query->useResultCache(true);
        }

    }
    else{

        $query = $qb->getQuery();

       if( $enable_cache ){
           $query->setResultCacheLifetime(30);
           $query->useResultCache(true);
       }

        return $query->getSingleScalarResult();

    }

    $results    = $query->getResult(AbstractQuery::HYDRATE_OBJECT);

    //--- filter by rank ---//
    $results    = new Collections\ArrayCollection( $results );
```

Between Content and ContentRank entity there is a one-to-one relationship defined below:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ContentRank", mappedBy="content", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $content_rank;
```

On staging I have regenerated proxy classes and created all of the tables. however could not get the dql to work, unless I remove all of the references to ContentRank (e.g. r, homepage_rank and so on). Even just adding `->leftjoin('d.content_rank', 'r')` causes the query to fail with a QueryException thrown from `Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php on line 49`.

The staging database is hosted on RDS. I don't understand what's going on!

Comment: hmm seems to be related to `Doctrine\Common\Cache\ApcCache` as when I disable it in my config and use ArrayCache the DQL works... Still need the cache tho... .

Comment: Updating php from *5.5.9-1ubuntu4.9* to *5.5.9-1ubuntu4.11* seems to have solved the problem.